# Check if Certificate Signature is MD5 OpenSSL

Tags: c, openssl

I need to check if a X509 certificate's signature algorithm is MD5 or SHA. To do this I know I can extract the NID corresponding to the signature algorithm:

```
int sig_nid = OBJ_obj2nid(cert->sig_alg->algorithm);
```

Now the problem is that I can't seem to find an easy way to compare this against MD5 or SHA as I do believe multiple NIDs can be returned for a signature. Is there an easy way to compare this NID or a place where I could find all MD5 and SHA NIDs so that I could do a long comparison myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're after: http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.2.840.113549.1.1.html It lists the hash/encryption available for X509 certificates. You can generate the nids you're comparing against using `OBJ_txt2nid()`.

The so you want to compare the algorithm nid to `OBJ_txt2nid("1.2.840.113549.1.1.4")` - or in practice `NID_md5WithRSAEncryption` (defined in `openssl/objects.h`)

Edit:
Just to add some more info: The [X509v3 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.2) refers to other RFCs which define "acceptable" algorithms. These are [RFC3279](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279), [RFC4055](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4055), and [RFC4491](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4491). They all include OIDs which can be used. Only the first one seems to define schemes with MD5 hashing.

Comment: Does this also include other possible key types for instance  ECDSA keys using MD5?

Comment: I thought ECDSA are only defined with sha*, but I may be wrong. Quick google search also doesn't bring up anything with md5.

Comment: Ah well say I wanted to extend this to SHA in the future is there an equivalent link? I'll edit the question